# Expire the source code after certain time

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, dll, .net-4.0

We have to deliver some source code for asp.net website (.net framework 4) to the customer Before receiving the Payment.

I am wondering if there is some way (by means of some code or tool etc.) that we can expire/invalidate the source code after some set period of time so that the customer will not be able to Build / Compile / Publish the website? And already published one should stop working automatically.

Comment: The customer has the complete source code?

Comment: _"We have to deliver some source code for asp.net website (.net framework 4) to the customer Before receiving the Payment."_ - I hope you have got a good lawyer and can afford him...

Comment: The answer is no. I think this is more of a business management and ethics questions. The question really is why are you in this situation in the first place (rhetorically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. As soon as you give that source code to them they can analyze it and remove your protections. You could obfuscate it to make it harder for them but the only way to truly prevent being ripped off here is to not give them the code. Host it yourself on some server somewhere, show them and say "look; it works.. pay now and receive the code"